# Nmap - Specify which probe(s) to use?

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to specify probe types for nmap to use. For example, I want to scan a subnet (say 192.168.0.0/24) and probe every port on every host to see if a web server is running on that port - the goal being to find a service running on unusual ports.

I understand that by default nmap checks the most common probe/port combinations. I also understand that the -sV --version-all option will attempt all probes on all specified ports. However, this is very time consuming, and if I only care about finding webservers running on unusual ports, I don't need to use all available probes. There's got to be a faster way.

Also, I'm relatively new to the StackExchange community; if this question would be better placed in a different community/network, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the number of probes sent by using the `--version-intensity` option and selecting a lower intensity number. In the `nmap-service-probes` file, each probe has a `rarity` value, and if the rarity is higher than the intensity, the probe will not be sent (unless it's a particularly important probe for that port number, as indicated by the `ports` line). The vast majority of HTTP responses are found under the `GetRequest` and `GenericLines` probes, which have a `rarity` of 1. So the simple answer to your question is that this command will find most web servers with a minimum of probes sent:

```
nmap --version-intensity 1 -sV
```

You can also use `--version-light` as a shorthand for `--version-intensity 3`, which only adds a few extra probes.

Since you're only interested in HTTP servers, which do not have a banner, you can also reduce the amount of time spent waiting for a banner to the NULL probe by editing the `nmap-service-probes` file and changing the `totalwaitms` value to something smaller. Once you start making changes to `nmap-service-probes`, you may decide to take other actions like changing the rarity of all other probes to `9`, but be sure you change it back if you expect to use this file for any normal scanning. If you decide to make a custom `nmap-service-probes` file, you can use the `--versiondb` option to point to it instead of overwriting the one that ships with Nmap.

Comment: How do you edit the rarity of probes in `nmap-service-probes`?

Comment: @LTPCGO Below the relevant `Probe` line, find the line like `rarity 3` and change `3` or whatever number is there to a higher number.

Comment: I have never noticed that bit!  Editing the file is certainly the best way to achieve what OP wants, by editing that line, port numbers, and including valid regex for responses indicating a web-server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify exactly the probes in the command line, but you could delete those found in `nmap-service-probes` except for those you specifically require.  Alternatively you could compile your own using the [source](https://svn.nmap.org/) and editing `nmap/service_scan.cc` to only process `nextProbes` where `probe->getName()` matches a regex similar to `http.*`

Answer (score 0):

Of course `nmap` can do this - simply read the `man` page or `info` page to find out what arguments/switches/options to use.

And yes, this woul d be better off on superuser...

That said, if you use `zenmap` - a GUI front end for `nmap` - it lets you make those choices using a GUI, and then shows you the actual command line you would run for plain `nmap`.

[image]

Comment: The reason I made this post is because I've spent a considerable amount of time reading about nmap's many options and nothing I've read indicates that this is possible. You can specify which ports to scan with -p, but I want to scan for specific services using specific probes. -sV --version-all scans for *all* services using *all* probes, but I want to scan only for a specific service using a specific probe in order to save time. Yes, I'm familiar with Zenmap, but I don't know if it's possible to specify services/probes with Zenmap either.

Comment: This answer is quite aggressive and doesn't actually answer the question, OP clearly did research